# How to execute a .lnk file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in Ruby and I wanted to start an application in Ruby. But how do I do that, how do I open a .lnk file in Ruby?

Comment: Please post the contents of the file, and note your OS.

Comment: Do you want to execute or open the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file for reading with the `File#open` method:

```rb
File.open('file.ink') do |f|
  # process the file
end
```

To write to the file pass `w` as the second argument to `File#open`.